# Movement Script for a 3D Unity Game Using C# Not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a script to move my player for a 3D mobile game using `Rigidbody.MovePosition`. Below, I have attached the script that I have so far. I have tried testing it using Unity Remote 5, but nothing happens when I use the app. I would really appreciate any advice on what adjustments I should make to get it to function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 10.0f;

public Rigidbody rb;
public Vector2 movement;
private Touch touch;


void Start()
{
    rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
  
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
     moveCharacter(movement);
}

void moveCharacter(Vector2 direction)
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
             rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * speed *Time.deltaTime));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Using the below suggestions, I have adjusted the code, but now I'm getting  an error stating: `FixedUpdate() can not take parameters`.

```
sing System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    
    public Rigidbody rb;
    private Vector3 position;
    private Touch touch;
    private float width;
    private float height;
    
  
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        width = Screen.width;
        height = Screen.height;
    }

    void FixedUpdate(Vector2 direction)
    {
        if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {

                  Vector2 pos = touch.position;
                  pos.x = (pos.x - width) / width;
                  pos.y = (pos.y - height) / height;
                  position = new Vector3(-pos.x, pos.y, 0.0f);
                  rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are storing keyboard inputs in movement variable by using

```
movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
```

so when you are trying to test using phone, keyboard inputs are 0 hence no movement

use `movement = touch.position` to store the touch input in update function

eg:

```
if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector2 pos = touch.position;
        pos.x = (pos.x - width) / width;
        pos.y = (pos.y - height) / height;
        position = new Vector3(-pos.x, pos.y, 0.0f);

        // Position the cube.
        transform.position = position;
    }
```

Comment: When dealing with Rigidbody never use `transform.position = position;` as this breaks the physics and collision detection! As OP did use `rb.MovePosition(...)` in `FixedUpdate` instead

Comment: Yes, if you are moving rigidbody you should use MovePosition or velocity not transform.position I was just demonstrating how to read touch input.

Comment: Okay, I made the changes that you suggested and some additional adjustments, but I a now receiving a FixedUpdate() can not take parameters error. I've posted the new script above. What could be causing this type of an error?

Comment: change ```void FixedUpdate(Vector2 direction)``` with ```void FixedUpdate(){}```